# Checking for duplicate types in a list of types

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to check if the variadic list contains no duplicate types in c++ 14?

```
template <class... Ts>
bool is_unique() {
    ...
}

static_assert(is_unique<a, b, c>() == true,  ""); //true: No duplicates 
static_assert(is_unique<a, b, a>() == false, ""); //false: contains 2 a's
```

Comment: yes. a little template recursion should do it

Comment: @Brian yes possible , some template meta-programming on the way